# Finding all rectangles in Python list

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, 2d

I have a python list:

```
[
[1, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 2],
[7, 4, 5],
[5, 3, 7],
]
```

I need to find all rectangles (how many rectangles are there) in this 2D array that meet this criteria:
1. All numbers in that one rectangle must be the same
2. Number from that rectangle can't be anywhere else in the array
3. Not really a criteria but some extra info:
    Rectangles dimensions can be 1x1, 2x1, 2x2, 3x1, 3x2, 3x3, 3x4 and so on.

In this example there are 5 rectangles for numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

and numbers 3, 1, 8 don't meet the criteria because:

5 - Breaks rule number 2
7 - Breaks rule number 2

I tried stuff like finding nearest elements that comparing them and if they match go down one row and so on but I couldn't do it so I hope someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Comment: I spent more than 3 hours on working on this problem and couldn't figure out the solution. You don't need to be rude.

Comment: Other users may have commented in a friendlier tone than me but with the same meaning: Show that you really worked on this for hours by showing the code of the best effort you have tried.

Comment: For each number in the array, find the upper-left coordinates, the lower-right coordinates, and the count of that number. You can then compute the expected count based on the coordinates, and compare with the actual count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is for each unique value, fit a rectangle over all instances of that value. If all values within that rectangle match, then you've met your criteria. Here it is implemented in code using numpy, printing values that match the criteria:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [3, 2, 2, 1, 4],
    [3, 2, 2, 7, 4],
    [8, 2, 2, 1, 3],
    [8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
    [8, 8, 1, 5, 1]
])
for n in np.unique(arr):
    y, x = np.where(arr == n)
    if (arr[y.min():y.max()+1, x.min():x.max()+1] == n).all():
        print(n)
```

---

Update

Not as pretty but this something like this would not require numpy:

```
lst = [
    [3, 2, 2, 1, 4],
    [3, 2, 2, 7, 4],
    [8, 2, 2, 1, 3],
    [8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
    [8, 8, 1, 5, 1]
]

for val in set([x for sub in lst for x in sub ]):
    y = [n for n, sub in enumerate(lst) if val in sub]
    if any(y):
        x = []
        for sub in [lst[n] for n in y]:
            x.extend([m for m, v in enumerate(sub) if v == val])

        rect = [i for sub in lst[min(y):max(y)+1] for i in sub[min(x):max(x)+1]]
        if all([i == val for i in rect]):
            print(val)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without Numpy, and just using Python.

Comment: Your answer is correct but do you maybe know how to translate this into pure Python.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comment above from user3386109, here is the pure python code that will calculate the rectangle size from the top left coordinate to the bottom right coordinate and compare that to the total digits and see if they equal. If they do, then the digit is a rectangle.

```
# create an empty result array
result = []

# check each digit one through nine
for num in range(1, 10):
    # create a list to store the coordinates of each found digit
    coords = []
    # rows loop
    for r in range(len(li)):
        # columns loop
        for c in range(len(li[0])):
            if li[r][c] == num:
                coords.append([r,c])
    # check for null coords list which means the digit is not in the matrix
    if len(coords) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        tl = coords[0]
        br = coords[-1]
        total = (br[0] - tl[0] + 1) * (br[1] - tl[1] + 1)
        if total == len(coords):
            result.append(num)
print('The digits that form rectangles are: ', result)
```

The result will look like this:

```
The digits that form rectangles are:  [2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to consider using a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Make a dataframe from your list of numbers as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
[3, 2, 2, 1, 4],
[3, 2, 2, 7, 4],
[8, 2, 2, 1, 3],
[8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
[8, 8, 1, 5, 1]
])
```

Then you use a for loop to test each number 1-9 (I'm assuming 0 is not in your list?) and in the for loop you drop the rows and columns that don't have any of the number being tested. If the resulting frame is indeed a rectangle, then there should be no 'NaN's present.

For example, the digit 1 resulting frame looks like:

```
      2   3   4
0    NaN 1.0 NaN
2    NaN 1.0 NaN
4    1.0 NaN 1.0
```

Whereas the digit 2 resulting frame looks like:

```
     1   2
0   2.0 2.0
1   2.0 2.0
2   2.0 2.0
```

Check for NaN's being == 0 and you will have a rectangle. You also need to make sure the size of the field is not zero, as this would indicate a number not present. Here's the code:

```
result = []
for num in range(1, 10):
    df_dna = df[df == num].dropna(how="all", axis=0).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    if df_dna.isnull().sum().sum() == 0 and df_dna.size != 0:
        result.append(num)
print("The numbers that form rectangles are:", result)
```

And your result looks like this:

```
The numbers that form rectangles are: [2, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: The answer that guy before you gave is good but I need someone to translate it to pure Python and not use Numpy if possible.